# Sign MyAssembly.XMLSerializers.dll

Tags: vb.net

I have an assembly, which I have installed in the GAC.  There is another assembly in the project called: MyAssembly.XMLSerializers.dll.  I now know what this assembly is after reading here: [Why does MSBuild put *.XmlSerializers.dll assembly in the root folder of published web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106484/why-does-msbuild-put-xmlserializers-dll-assembly-in-the-root-folder-of-publish).

This assembly is not strongly typed so I cannot add it to the GAC as it stands.  Is there a way of strongly typing this assembly in Visual Studio i.e. without manually decompiling it signing it and then compiling it again.

I know how to mark a DLL as signed (by decompiling it and recompiling it).  I was wandering if there was a way of visual studio signing the DLL when it generates it.

Comment: The Sgen.exe utility uses the /compiler option to pass options to the compiler.  You want /keyfile

Comment: @Hans Passant, can this be done in Visual Studio or does it have to be outside visual studio in a command prompt?

Comment: Sorry for marking it as a duplicate.  You're right, it is a slightly different question.  I should have just provided a link to the other question in the comments, which I will do now...  Here's [a link to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220519/how-to-sign-a-net-assembly-dll-file-with-a-strong-name) which provides some interesting related details.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, thanks.  Surely there is an option in Visual Studio to generate this file with a strong name?